# YouTube like progress bar to appear each time a link is clicked?

Tags: youtube, progress-bar

I found this [JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajaSB/109/) for a YouTube like progress bar but I don't know how to make the progress bar appear each time a link is clicked. Does anyone have any ideas on how I can do this?

HTML:

```
<div id="progress" class="waiting">
    <dt></dt>
    <dd></dd>           
</div>
```

CSS:

```
body {
background-color:#D4D4E2;
}

#progress {
    position:fixed;
    z-index:2147483647;
    top:0;
    left:-6px;
    width:0%;
    height:2px;
    background:#3399FF;
    -moz-border-radius:1px;
    -webkit-border-radius:1px;
    border-radius:1px;
    -moz-transition:width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
    -ms-transition:width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
    -o-transition:width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
    -webkit-transition:width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear;
    transition:width 500ms ease-out,opacity 400ms linear
}
#progress.done {
    opacity:0
}
#progress dd,#progress dt {
    position:absolute;
    top:0;
    height:2px;
    -moz-box-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 0 6px 1px;
    -ms-box-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 0 6px 1px;
    -webkit-box-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 0 6px 1px;
    box-shadow:#FFFFFF 1px 0 6px 1px;
    -moz-border-radius:100%;
    -webkit-border-radius:100%;
    border-radius:100%
}
#progress dd {
    opacity:1;
    width:20px;
    right:0;
    clip:rect(-6px,22px,14px,10px)
}
#progress dt {
    opacity:1;
    width:180px;
    right:-80px;
    clip:rect(-6px,90px,14px,-6px)
}
@-moz-keyframes pulse {
    30% {
        opacity:1
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1
    }
}
@-ms-keyframes pulse {
    30% {
        opacity:.6
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        opacity:.6
    }
}
@-o-keyframes pulse {
    30% {
        opacity:1
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1
    }
}
@-webkit-keyframes pulse {
    30% {
        opacity:.6
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        opacity:.6
    }
}
@keyframes pulse {
    30% {
        opacity:1
    }
    60% {
        opacity:0
    }
    100% {
        opacity:1
    }
}
#progress.waiting dd,#progress.waiting dt {
    -moz-animation:pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
    -ms-animation:pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
    -o-animation:pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
    -webkit-animation:pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite;
    animation:pulse 2s ease-out 0s infinite
}
```

Javascript:

```
$({property: 0}).animate({property: 105}, {
    duration: 4000,
    step: function() {
        var _percent = Math.round(this.property);
        $('#progress').css('width',  _percent+"%");
        if(_percent == 105) {
            $("#progress").addClass("done");
        }
    },
});
```